Wordpress Navigation Change Post Type Recipes
I imported a theme that works great for my however it has a Post type that say Recipes and I would like it to be news and I cannot figure out how to change that. Any advice would be appreciated.
This is not under the normal Menu maybe its somewhere in the theme I cannot edit?
Tom


If all you need is to rename that entry in the Wordpress dashboard menu, you can use the "Admin Menu Editor" plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/admin-menu-editor/
